# Display Bitmap using send_file and add meta refresh tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bitmap

I’m using the `send_file` method to display a Bitmap with the attachment set to inline, like so:

```
def index
   ..
  create_image_from_html
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      send_file("luna.bmp", type: 'image/bmp', disposition: 'inline')
    end
  end
end

def create_image_from_html
  kit = IMGKit.new(render_to_string, width: 1024, height: 1280)
  kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/public/assets/" + "#{self.class.helpers.asset_digest_path('application.css')}"
  kit.to_file('kit.jpg')
  bitmap_from_image('kit.jpg')
end

def bitmap_from_image(file)
  # Generate the Bitmap
  MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
    convert << file # input
    convert.merge! ["-monochrome"] # options
    convert << "luna.bmp" # output
  end
end
```

Now this works fine. But I want the page to refresh each x seconds. For this I implemented the refresh meta tag:
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="500" />`

This doesn’t work. It only works, if I display HTML instead of rendering the Bitmap, which I don’t want.

How can I display the Bitmap and still refresh the page each x seconds?